# C#: splitting incoming serial data and output to separate textbox

Tags: c#

I am reading in data from a serial port in C#. Currently I have two sensors on my micro-controller, and I am receiving data from both sensors in my application.

The incoming looks like so:
`:*123*188;` where,
`:` represents start of data

`*` first occurrence indicates sensor 1 data

`*` second occurrence indicates sensor 2 data

`;` represents end of data

To get rid of the punctuations I have used:

```
var DataPacket = SensorData.Split(new[]{":",";"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Now I have left: *123*188. How do I separate the two sensors data and put them in different textbox.

I have tried:

```
foreach(var Data in DataPacket)
{
    string bits[] = Data.Split(new[] {"*"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);     
}
```

But, `textbox1.Text = bits[0]` is reading both sensor 1 and sensor 2 values in the same box. And `bits[1]` is out of bound.

Please guide me to solving this.

Edit: Here is the extended code that reads data and tries to split it accordingly:

private void OnReceive(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs s)
        {
                //FOR 1 SENSOR
                string SensorData = AvailablePort.ReadLine();
                this.BeginInvoke(new LineReceivedEvent(LineReceived), SensorData);

```
    }

    private delegate void LineReceivedEvent(string SensorData);

    private void LineReceived(string SensorData)
    {

       /*** FOR SECOND SENSOR****************/ 
        int startReading = SensorData.IndexOf(":");
        int endReading = SensorData.IndexOf(";");
        /********                   ************/

        //int userRange = Convert.ToInt32(Temp_Range.SelectedValue);
        //int data = Int32.Parse(SensorData);


        /*** FOR SECOND SENSOR ************************************************/
        var DataPacket = SensorData.Split(new[] { ":", ";" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        foreach (var Data in DataPacket)
        {
            //textBox1.Text = Data;
            //TRYING TO READ MORE THAN 1 SENSOR HERE
            var newData = SensorData.Split(new[] { "*" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            while(true)
            {
                foreach (var data in newData)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = data[0].ToString();
                }
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Is the data going to be variable length or is going to be the same lentgh i.e. 3 digits from each sensor?

Comment: That split would definitely work.  So it is another problem.  Most typically its trying to use the data from the serial port before you got the entire response.  Make sure you keep reading until you got the ';'

Comment: @HansPassant: The split is definitely working. I say so because after SensorData.Split I have *123*188. And when I try split *123*188, I get the two values without * but both values are in bit[0]. If I say that textbox1.Text = bit[0] and textbo2.Text = bit[1] then I get index out of bound for bit[1] and textbox1 keeps switching between 123 & 188 (i.e. both values are in bit[0]).

Comment: Can you please put the next two lines of codes as well, just to see the context. Are you assigning the values outside the the foreach loop or inside the loop. The full code for this part would certainly help us understand. Thanks

Comment: I have added more code for a better understanding.

Comment: @LiaqatG: The data is going to be variable length. It will not always be 3 digit.

Answer (score 0):

Do not add StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries if you want to include null or empty elements.
ex:

```
Without remove
*121
a[0]=null
a[1]=121
121*
a[0]=121
a[1]=null
111*222
a[0]=111
a[1]=222


with remove
*121
a[0]=121
a[1]=OutOfRangeException
121*
a[0]=121
a[1]=OutOfRangeException
111*222
a[0]=111
a[1]=222
```

Comment: ok I changed StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries with StringSplitOptions.None   and I still get out of bound for bit[1].

Comment: If value="101*" then value.Split(star)[0]="101" and value.split(star)[1]=NULL OR EMPTY. Check the begin and end of your value.

Comment: So say if value = 101*102*, will then it be, value.Split(star)[0] = 101 and then second time around value.Split(star)[0] = 102? If so how can I make it value.Split(star)[0] = 101, & value.Split(star)[1] = 102?

Comment: Yea..what is the semantics of you data....with the simple bit it seems like a value is there or not there. If the list is long then place the values in a var such as Item[0]...I don't know. Your string parsing in as to youyr origibaly post if now it has changed..

Answer (score 0):

I don't a Visual Studio here but you should try something like this :

```
string bits[] = Data.Split("*");
```

this should give you this :

```
bits[0] = null;
bits[1] = 123;
bits[2] = 188;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there seems to be some code ambiguity for me here, but I think you need to change the following line of code:

```
var newData = SensorData.Split(new[] { "*" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
while(true)
{
      foreach (var data in newData)
      {
            textBox1.Text = data[0].ToString(); // Remove the index from data as this is not a collection but a variable
      }
}
```

I think you should rewrite this bit of code as follows:

```
String[] newData = SensorData.Split(new[] { "*" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
for(int i=0; i<newData.Length; i++)
{
    textBox1.Text = newData[i]; // You will need to manipulate the textboxes better here, since the
}
```

Now I may be wrong in understanding but I think this should work for you apart from changes in assigning these values to the textboxes as you seem to have hardcoded them. For instance the for loop could be replaced with something like this:

```
switch(newData.Length)
{
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        textbox1.Text = newData[0];
        break;
    case 2:
        textbox1.Text = newData[0];
        textbox2.Text = newData[1];
        break;
    ...
    case n:
        break;
}
```

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with the way you extract the data, but just make sure the data you get the from serial port really follow the pattern , is it possible you program continues before it read to the end of the data?

Comment: The data I provided is just 1 sample. Actually the data keeps coming in constantly but in same pattern. So the whole code is continuously looping, extracting and giving the data output.

Comment: yeah, is it possible that your loop kicked off while when the data ":*123" , then you will have problems ,  I think serial port read data byte by byte, or it will raise event based on the threshold you set, try to debug the data which you get from serial port, you should be able to figure it.